# Does OV2640 apply flip/mirror operation before or after windowing?

Tags: camera, camera-calibration

The [datasheet](https://www.uctronics.com/download/OV2640_DS.pdf) of the OV2640 camera mentions the possibility to mirror or flip the image (see "REG04"). For my application it is, however, crucial to know the location of each pixel. Since the camera also crops the 1632x1232 sensor to a smaller, e.g., 1600x1200 image, the order of operations is important.

[image]

So does the camera first crop the image to the 1600x1200 window and mirror/flip it *afterwards*, or does the mirror/flip happen *before* the windowing?

Comment: can you _experiment_ with the windowing? -- this is not something random people on this site can help with. you yourself say the datasheet doesn't specify this. your only recourse is to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: I didn't say the datasheet wouldn't specify it. Maybe the information is in the functional block diagram or somewhere else and I just don't see or understand it. I was hoping that someone has experience with this or a similar camera chip and/or knows how things are usually done. E.g. one or the other order of operation might be more natural to implement efficiently.

Comment: try asking on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ because that's where you'll find the kind of people that deal with this -- I browsed the datasheet. it's meagre. just send OV an email or something. if they suck at making this clear and easy to find in the datasheet, they ought to improve the datasheet. I often deal with electronics, and bad datasheets. the only solution is to strangle and shake the manufacturer until the information falls out. -- or just set the window and toggle mirroring on and off and see what it does. intuitively I'd say it crops first, then mirrors...